# Console.ReadLine().ToString() generates error

Tags: c#

I never did Console programming so got stuck in this silly thing:

```
Console.Write("Enter customer's salary: ");
string sal = Console.Write("{0}! ", Console.ReadLine().ToString());
```

It generates error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Console.Write` is a void method, it does not return what it writes to the console.
What you actually need is `string.Format`:

```
string sal = string.Format("{0}! ", Console.ReadLine());
```

Also, the extra `ToString()` at the end is redundant (as noted in the comments) for two reasons:

1. `Console.ReadLine` already returns a string
2. String formatting functions accept objects as parameters, they automatically convert to string if needed.

Comment: What's with the extra ToString on the end? ReadLine() already returns a string.

Comment: @John: Actually it is a leftover of some research. Initially 'sal' was decimal. I am not following why we need to use string.Format. Isn't there any shorter way to directly get the Decimal value? But I don't want to use those 'Convert' things.

Comment: @RPK - Sorry, that was directed at Paolo, not you. The data will be read in as a string no matter whether it is numeric or alpha text. So you don't need to append ToString on the end of ReadLine. It looks like he already corrected that, so you should be good.